# Question about the domain of a function in the definition of the derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces, definition

The following definition of the derivative of a function is taken from Analysis on Manifolds by James Munkres:

[image]

Now my question is the following:  Is the "neighborhood of $a$" an open set $U⊆A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (the parent space) containing $a$ or is $U$ open in the subspace $A$?

I'm assuming that $U$ must be open in $\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to the subspace $A$ because then we could have all kinds of wacky domains (e.g a discrete subset of $[0,1]$ for the the function $f$ in which case the derivative wouldn't even exist (because the limit wouldn't even exist)).

In that case we can only take the derivative of functions that are defined on "nice-ish" sets (i.e. sets that have non-empty interiors). Am I correct in this observation?

Comment: @fleablood Yes it does, but open with respect to which space? Here I think it's a bit ambiguous as it could mean open in $\mathbb{R}$ or open in the subsapce $A$

Comment: Ah, I see  Well "provided the limit exists" takes care for wacky (so what if its discreet and the limit doesn't exist?  If the limit doesn't exist it's simply not differentiable).  Also I don't see anything wrong with $A = \mathbb Q$.  So I'd say no.  It doesn't have any such requirement.

Comment: @fleablood So I'd say my question is more of a pedagogical issue than anything else? What I mean by this is that I could form an equivalent definition of the derivative by instead assuming as a priori that $A$ had the requirements I stated. Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: The say $A$ is a sub*set* of $\mathbb R$.  Not a subspace.  So by that definition the neighborhood is open in $\mathbb R$.  So $\phi:\mathbb Q\to R$ can't seem to have a derivative.  Not sure why that is not allowed.

Comment: @fleablood Are you saying then that $\phi : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ would possess a derivative?

Comment: I am saying that it could but I'm probably wrong for some obviously reason I'm overlooking.  Anyway it does seem like you were right despite my earlier comment.  By *this* definition $A$ is a sub*set* not a space and there is a neighborhood in the *reals* not a neighborhood in $A$'s non-existent topology.  So the domain is in the real I don't see why we need a neighborhood to define a limit.  But I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when it says "a neighborhood of $a$" it means a neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}$.  By this definition, the derivative of a function at a point is only defined when the point is in the interior of the domain of the function.

(This requirement is not at all intrinsic to the notion of "derivative", and you could define derivatives without requiring $f$ to be defined on an entire neighborhood of $a$.  But it is convenient to have an entire neighborhood as part of the definition so that you don't have to constantly state extra hypotheses for your theorems, many of which involve such a neighborhood.)